# ASP.NET Web API listens on 0.0.0.0 instead 127.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, localhost, netstat

My ASP.NET Web API is bound to localhost:

```
startOptions.Urls.Add("http://localhost:8080");
```

If I now call `netstat -a` I would have expected to see something like `127.0.0.1:8080` but it looks like my binding works on all IP addresses on the local machine:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           MyComputer:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8888              MyComputer:0            LISTENING
```

Do I have to worry about external (e.g. non-localhost) connections?

Comment: I don't think that is the binding part. Can you post rest of the code you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes", since this port *may* be routable by others you *may* need to worry about external connections, but it depends on your specific environment.  Use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost loop back address, 127.0.0.1 and then you won't have to have external access concerns:

```
startOptions.Urls.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8080");
```

Your question has to do with the default route, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route.

*FYI: You may want to have a configuration that switches this when you deploy so it can have access when you want it to...*

Additionally, https://ifconfig.co/port/8080 may be able to help you determine if your port is exposed...

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0:8080 is also a DroidScript address used for "no touch" mobile phone "hacking" it is not solely limited to DroidScript as many users of JS use it across a wide variety of web tools